# Implementing an Upper Bounded Generic Method

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard, generic-method

I am having trouble building a somewhat circular generic configuration. I need a "state" interface that provides a getter to a generic "container" interface. The container interface on its methods needs to accept a generic "state" as one of the parameters. I have tried various options (truly circular generic class parameters, various variations of below), but what I have below is the closest to what I think I need:

```
interface Container<K> {
    <C extends Container<K>,S extends State<K,C>> C setData(K key, Object val,S state);
}

interface State<K,C extends Container<K>>{
    C getContainer();
}

class BasicContainer<K> implements Container<K> {
    public <C extends BasicContainer<K>, S extends State<K,C>> C setData(K key, Object val, S state) { return this;}
}

class BasicState<K> implements State<K,BasicContainer<K>> {
    BasicContainer<K> container = new BasicContainer<K>();
    public BasicContainer<K> getContainer(){
        return container;
    }
}
```

Alas, the compiler is giving the famous `methods have same erasure yet neither overrides the other` for the `BasicContainer` method. I believe this is because while `C extends BasicContainer<K>` is a subtype of `C extends Container<K>`, `S extends State<K,C>` is *not* a subtype of `S extends State<K,C>` in `Container<K>`.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish by desired configuration?

**Update**
I will need other implementations of `Container` that also need to work with a `State` implementation, but the `State` implementation will not return those implementations. This is where the circular parameters on a class failed.

Comment: It looks like `C` ought to be a type parameter on the `Container` interface, like `K`.

Comment: Just saw your comment, let me think about that. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `C` ought to be a type parameter on the `Container` interface, like `K`.

In general, if `Foo` is a supertype of `Bar`, `Bar` *cannot* add additional constraints to generic type parameters on methods from `Foo`.  This just follows from the Liskov substitution principle: any `Bar` must be able to be used for *anything* a `Foo` can be used for.

Constraining `C extends BasicContainer<K>` in the type parameters of `BasicContainer.setData`, when `Container.setData` only has the constraint `C extends Container<K>`, specifically violates this rule.

What you can do instead is have the upper bound on `C` as a type parameter on `Container,` and set it to a different value in `BasicContainer`.

This could look like one of the following:

```
interface Container<K, C extends Container<K, C>> {
    <S extends State<K,C>> C setData(K key, Object val,S state);
}
class BasicContainer<K> implements Container<K, BasicContainer<K>> { ... }
```

...or, if you find you need the additional generics,

```
interface Container<K, C extends Container<K, C>> {
    <C2 extends C, S extends State<K,C>> C2 setData(K key, Object val,S state);
}
class BasicContainer<K> implements Container<K, BasicContainer<K>> { ... }
```

(though bluntly, the second version is almost certainly not what you want).